# limiting requests and authenticating the user in rest api

Tags: python, rest, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I have a machine learning model which I have converted as a Rest API using Django rest framework. Now I want to distribute the API to users but how can I authenticate and limit the requests by the users by allowing them to interact the api using an api key?. And also I want to mask the URL of the API before giving to the users how can I do this in django rest framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you have full control of the requirements I would consider using JWT tokens. A simple library to do this is [Simple Jwt](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), follow the steps in the wiki to configure it.

To rate limit check [Django Rest Framework Throttling module](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/).